# Exercise $7$, Section $3.A$ - Linear Algebra Done Right

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

Exercise : Show that every linear map from a $1$-dimensional vector space to itself is
multiplication by some scalar. More precisely, prove that if $\dim V = 1$
and $T \in L(V, V)$, then there exists $\lambda \in F$ such that $Tv = \lambda v$ for all
$v \in V$.

$L(V,V)$ denotes the set of all linear maps $T : V \to V$. $F$ denotes the field of real or complex numbers.

I might be misinterpreting this question, but the following was my attempt at proving that. I am assuming that $V=\{\lambda v : \lambda \in F,v\in W\}$ where $W$ is another vector space. In other words, $V$ is a subspace of $W$.

Proof: Let $v\in V$. Then $T(v)\in V$ by definition of $T$. Then by definition of $V$, we have that $T(v)=\lambda v$. Thus, there exists a scalar $\lambda \in F$ such that $Tv=\lambda v$.

Am I misunderstanding the question or is this proof correct?

Edit: I will update this post once I find a correct proof.

Edit 2: The following is the correct proof.

Proof: Let $u\in V$ where $u=\lambda v$. Then, $Tu=T(\lambda v)=\lambda T(v)=\lambda \lambda 'v=\lambda'\lambda v=\lambda'u$

Hence, ther exists a scalar $\lambda ' \in F$ such that for any $u\in V$ and every $T \in L(V, V)$ we have that $Tu=\lambda 'u$.

Edit 3: As pointed out in the comments, it is not necessary to use $W$. I was just confusing myself.

Comment: What's the point of $W$?  You can actually write $V$ for $W$.  On your proof,  you still need to show that for any other element $v'\in V$ that $T(v')=\lambda v'$.

Comment: @Cpc Oh yeah I just realised that. I was confusing myself with that. For the proving part, I realise I used $v$ in my proof. I meant that any arbitrary vector in $V$. Does the proof hold then?

Comment: @Cpc Oh no, never mind. I got what you mean. That proof is wrong. Thanks for the help.

Comment: No, because you need to establish that for a different vector you get multiplication by that same $\lambda $.  Shall I write a solution?   Or maybe you should.

Comment: @Cpc I realised what you meant. I will update the post once I find the correct proof.

Comment: Just use the fact that any two vectors in $V$ are multiples of each other.

Comment: @Cpc Yeah I got that. I was just about type it up.

Comment: Matrix of T is a $1×1$ matrix $[a]$ which is scalar ($a$) multiple of $[1]$

Comment: @LostinSpace Yeah that also works!

Comment: Good.   Just be careful with your quantifiers.  For a different $T$ it will be a different $\lambda '$.  You could even say for each $T$ there's a $\lambda _T$.

Comment: $\lambda_T$ can be made unique.

Answer (score 2):

Let $w\in V$ be a nonzero vector then $\{w\}$ is the basis of $V$ (because $\dim V=1$).
Since $T$ is a linear operator it follows that $T(w) \in V$ then there is $\lambda \in F$ such that $T(w) = \lambda w$.

Now, let $v \in V$ be arbitrary then there exists $c\in F$ such that $v=cw$. On other hand,
\begin{equation*}
T(v) = T(cw)=cT(w)=c(\lambda w)=\lambda(cw)=\lambda v.
\end{equation*}

Answer (score 0):

There is no need nor justification for introducing a vector space $W$ that contains $V$. An important hypothesis (which must be used somewhere) is $\dim(V)=1$ which means that $V$ admits a basis (at least one, but it will not be unique) that has exactly one vector. And the statement to be proved is that *there exists* a scalar $\lambda$ such that *for all* vectors $v\in V$ one has $T(v)=\lambda v$. This is not the same as showing (as you appear to do) that for all vectors $v\in V$ there exists a scalar $\lambda$ such that $T(v)=\lambda v$ (which is a weaker statement).

So here is an outline of how your proof could proceed. Since a basis of $V$ with exactly one vector exists, let $[u]$ be such a basis. This means that $u\neq\vec0$ (since a zero vector cannot be member of a basis), and every vector in $V$ can be written (uniquely) as a scalar multiple of $u$, i.e., as $\mu u$ for some scalar$~\mu$. (I avoided the letters $v$ and $\lambda$ since they are used as bound variables in the statement to prove, so using them elsewhere may be confusing.)

Now given a linear $T:V\to V$ find a candidate scalar $\lambda$ for which you claim will hold (there is a bit work to do here, and the chosen basis vector $u$ will be useful to find a candidate.) Now let $v\in V$ be an arbitrary vector; show that $T(v)=\lambda v$ for the proposed candidate; this establishes the claim. (Though not asked, it is also true that $\lambda$ is unique; there is only one candidate that will do. Your argument should make this clear in passing.)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I figured that out soon after I posted the question. I was just confusing myself. I have updated the post with the correct proof and mentioned that we do not need to include $W$.

Comment: But the proof you gave after editing is not correct. For starters, where do you use that $\dim(V)=1$? "Let $u\in V$ where $u=\lambda v$" is a bad way of formulating; either you choose $u\in V$ freely, or you define it by an expression, but you cannot do both at the same time. You could say "Let $u=\lambda v$" if you explain where $\lambda$ and  $v$ come from (which you don't). Finally you get your fixed scalar $\lambda'$ at the end of your argument; as I stressed it must be found _before_ you take an arbitrary vector $v\in V$.

Comment: @Seeker since you haven't proved $\lambda$ is unique, it is better to write $Tu=\lambda_u u$ . For $v\neq u$ , we have $Tv=\lambda_vv$ . But you are lucky enough $(\lambda_u=\lambda_v) $.But it requires a proof.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I keep pressing enter by accident when trying to type my comment. ignore the previous comments. Sorry for that

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I hear what you're saying. I agree I should have written my proof better. When writing the proof I meant the following: By definition of $V$ we see that $v$ is a basis of $V$ and thus $\dim V = 1$. Let $u\in V$. By definition of $V$, we have that there exists a scalar $\lambda_u \in F$ such that $u=\lambda_u v$. For $T\in L(V, V)$, we have that $T(u) = T(\lambda_uv)= \lambda_u T(v)=\lambda_u \lambda_Tv = \lambda_Tu$. Although I realise that this proof does resemble my edited proof.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I just saw that someone posted a similar answer above. I want to say that this was independent of that one.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

Given $\dim V_F=1$ and $T\in\mathcal{L}(V) $ has an eigenvalue, say $\lambda$ (linear polynomial always split!)

Then the eigenspace $E(\lambda, T) =V$

$[$$E(\lambda,T)$ is subspace of $V$ containg a non zero vector$]$

i.e $Tv=\lambda v$ for all $v\in V$ and fixed scalar $\lambda$.

Comment: This seems like an exercise made to introduce the notion of eigenvectors; using theory of diagonalisation to solve it would then not be appropriate. Also Axler does not use characteristic polynomials to solve eigenvalue problems, because he does not like determinants.

Comment: I know this can be solved more easily (an elementary problem) .Strictly speaking, we don't need determinant to compute eigenvalue here. It follows immediately from the fact that $V=\text{span}\{v_0\}$.$\\$I like determinant(and Gilbert Strang) . It's an efficient tool in finite dimensional analysis.